# jQuery - Toggle menu without using stopImmediatePropagation();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently the snippet only allows toggling of each menu when I un-comment the `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`.

The problem is I cannot use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` because I have to use an animation on the `.button` that would be killed by the stop.

How do I change the code to be able to toggle the menu's as is done when using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, but not have to use it.

> **To emulate problem:** Click the Apple or Google logo (or Bell Icon) and then click it
>   again. The solution should remove `.active` from it's associated
>   `.modal` and it should close just like it does when clicking `document` (except for Bell Icon button which isn't set up to close when document is clicked). I just don't know how to acheive this without using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```js
$("[data-close]").click(function(e) {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length ?
    $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]') :
    $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
    /* e.stopImmediatePropagation();*/
  }
});
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).prop("id");
  $(".modal").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal, .google-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#icon {
  color: silver;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" data-close="google" />
  <img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
  <div class="button" id="icon" data-close="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal google-modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal icon-modal" data-id="icon">
  <div class="header">Icon</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Toggling for me works in Firefox and Chrome no meter the line is commented or not, and Safari it does not work at all, also no matter the line is commented or not. I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also did you try using stopPropagation instead of stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: I have updated the question with a use case to emulate the issue. The solution cannot use stopPropagation as I have an animation on the button at site.

Comment: Yes I can see now the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to implement what you want by adding the close modal functionality inside the click button and check if the modal for the current element is visible or not:

```js
$(".button").on("click", function () {
  const dataClose = $(this).attr("data-close");
  const elem = $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]').length
    ? $('[data-id="' + dataClose + '"]')
    : $(dataClose);
  if (elem.hasClass("active") && elem.is(":visible")) {
    elem.removeClass("active");
  } else {
    const id = $(this).prop("id");
    $(".modal").each(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).data("id") == id);
    });
  }
});

$(document).on("click", function (e) {
  if (
    $(".apple-modal, .google-modal").hasClass("active") &&
    !$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target)
  ) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#icon {
  color: silver;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
    <img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" data-close="google" />
    <img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" data-close="apple" />
    <div class="button" id="icon" data-close="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal google-modal" data-id="google">
    <div class="header">Google</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            First
        </li>
        <li>
            Second
        </li>
        <li>
            Third
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal apple-modal" data-id="apple">
    <div class="header">Apple</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            First
        </li>
        <li>
            Second
        </li>
        <li>
            Third
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal icon-modal" data-id="icon">
    <div class="header">Icon</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            First
        </li>
        <li>
            Second
        </li>
        <li>
            Third
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by every other click, maybe I'm missing something, my implementation is a toggle functionality, which is exactly what you had with `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` enabled.

Comment: clicking apple, then clicking google back and forth a few times you can see that sometimes it requires additional clicking.

Comment: got it now, will  check it now.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill, check now.